# Tag a client to multiple screens

Tags: awesome

Using `Awesome Window Manager`, I am trying to tag one client to multiple screens. I tried to use the following configuration in my `rc.lua`, but it does not work:

```
{ rule = { class = "<the class>" },
callback = function(c) c:tags({ tags[1][2], tags[2][2] }) end },
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.window-managers.awesome/5379):

*"[...] this is a limitation of how X works. A client, or "window", has a specific x/y position and a screen it is
bound to."*

So unfortunately, it is apparently not possible...